# Error while rewriting from temp file

Tags: ruby, temporary-files

I'm writing to a file from a temp file, when I try to read the file that has been written from the temp file, it seems to be adding an extra character to the directory called `tmp`. (file is passed in through optparse)

Source:

```
require 'tempfile'

PATH = Dir.pwd

def format_file
  puts 'Writing to temporary file..'
  if File.exists?(OPTIONS[:file])
    file = Tempfile.new('file')
    IO.read(OPTIONS[:file]).each_line do |s|
      File.open(file, 'a+') { |format| format.puts(s) unless s.chomp.empty? }
    end
    IO.read(file).each_line do |file|
      File.open("#{PATH}/tmp/#sites.txt", 'a+') { |line| line.puts(file) }
    end
    puts "File: #{OPTIONS[:file]}, has been formatted and saved as #sites.txt in the tmp directory."
  else
    puts <<-_END_
                       Woah now my friend! I know you're eager to get those vulns;

                       But file: #{OPTIONS[:file]} doesn't exist or in this directory at least!

                       What I'm gonna need you to do is go move that file over here.
                       It's okay, you're forgiven, I'll wait until you return..
    _END_

  end
end
```

Example:

```
ruby whitewidow.rb -f sites.txt

[12:40:43 INFO]Formatting file
[12:40:43 INFO]Writing to temporary file..
[12:40:43 INFO]File: tmp/sites.txt, has been formatted and saved as #sites.txt in the tmp directory.
[12:40:43 INFO]Let's check out this file real quick like..
whitewidow.rb:224:in `read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:/Users/Justin/MyScripts/RubySQL/whitewidow/#tmp/#sites.txt (Errno::ENOENT)
#<= Correct path but the '#' in tmp shouldn't be there..
```

What it does is format the file to remove any empty lines within it (this program doesn't like empty lines) from there it should write to a temp file, rewrite from the temp file back to the original directory (whitewidow/tmp/) and delete the temp file (I know how to do this part).

It seems to me like while rewriting back to the original directory it's adding a `#` to the directory name (`#tmp` is actually `tmp`) is there a reason that it's adding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, for some reason the program was adding a `#` to the path, so I `gsub`ed out the `#` and it works.